# Objective C, how to use classes.

Tags: objective-c, class, header, cocos2d-iphone

I've just started working with Objective C, and either my design is wrong, or my implementation is wrong, or both, I don't even know.

I've given relevant information below, but my expectations are this:

***Create PlayerBullet class, so that I can just allocate data pre-defined in the class file, such as, sprite file, speed, sound when fired, etc.***

I assume that'd be better than setting that data in the playerShoot function every time a bullet is made.  However, I'm getting errors that suggest insertObject:atIndex:] object cannot be nil.

```
//PlayerBullet.h
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface PlayerBullet: CCSprite{
     CCSprite *projectile; 
}
property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite *projectile; 
@end
```

---

```
//PlayerBullet.m 
#import "PlayerBullet.h" 
@implementation PlayerBullet
-(id)init{
     projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile.png"]; 
     return self; 
 }
 @end
```

---

```
 //HelloWorldLayer.h
 ...
 @interface HellowWorldLayer: CCLayerColor{
       PlayerBullet *playerBullet; 
 }
 ...
```

---

```
 //HelloWorldLayer.m
 ...
-(void)playerShoot:(ccTime)dt{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]; 
    playerBullet = [[PlayerBullet alloc] init]; 
    playerBullet.projectile.tag = 2; 
    [_projectiles addObject:playerBullet.projectile]; 
    playerBullet.projectile.position = ccp(player.position.x,player.position.y); 
    [self addChild:playerBullet.projectile]; 

    [playerBullet.projectile runAction:
     [CCSequence actions: 
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.5  position:ccp(player.position.x,winSize.height)], 
      [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node){
          [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; 
          [_projectiles removeObject:node]; 
      }], 
       nil]]; 
}
```

Comment: There are many books on getting started with Objective-C and iOS development, they would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like to me that you are trying to create a PlayerBullet object that is a CCSprite subclass.  However, in [playerBullet init] you are not initializing self.

A typically example of initializing an object:

```
// SomeObject.m

@implementation SomeObject

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self; 
}

@end
```

For your object, try this:

```
    //PlayerBullet.m 
#import "PlayerBullet.h" 
@implementation PlayerBullet
-(id)init{
    self = [super init]; // initialize self
    if (self) {
        projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile.png"]; 
    }
    return self; 
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the correct answer.  I also decided to change the superclass to that of CSNode, since there was no reason for it to be a  CSSprite.